# How to update JwtBearer Authority and Audience on request

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

is there any way to change value of Authority and Audience on api execution,

We have multi tenancy application requirement, and based on tenant we need to change JWT TokenValidationParameters.

Current Code:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            //We need this to change on api header paramters
            options.Authority = "https://XXXXX/oauth2/default";
            options.Audience = "api://default";
        });
```

Comment: Do you want to dynamically authorize the requesting client? But the two parameters can not changed as the middleware.

Comment: hmm.. seems like no way to change these two variable